# Integral of least squares and general rules of integration to solve the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

My calculus is very rusty and I am interested to know if the following is solvable:

$$
\int_0^{\pi}(
    \log(
        \frac
            {(x_0 + e^{-i\omega})(x_0 + e^{i\omega})(x_1 + e^{-i\omega})(x_1 + e^{i\omega})}
            {(y_0 + e^{-i\omega})(y_0 + e^{i\omega})(y_1 + e^{-i\omega})(y_1 + e^{i\omega})}
    )
    -
    \log(
        \frac
            {(p_0 + i\omega)(p_0 - i\omega)(p_1 + i\omega)(p_1 - i\omega)}
            {(q_0 + i\omega)(q_0 - i\omega)(q_1 + i\omega)(q_1 - i\omega)}
    )
)^2 d\omega
$$

$x_n$, $y_n$, $p_n$, $q_n$ are constants.

If this is solvable what rules of integration can I use to solve it?

I know the following identities may be useful:

$$
e^{i\omega} + e^{-i\omega} = 2\cos(\omega) \qquad e^{i\omega} e^{-i\omega} = 1
$$

$$
\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b) \qquad \log(\frac{a}{b}) = \log(a) - \log(b)
$$

For some background, the general form of the equations is:

$$
\int_0^{\pi}(
    \log(
        \frac
            {\prod_{n=1}^N (x_n + e^{-i\omega}) \overline{(x_n + e^{-i\omega})}}
            {\prod_{m=1}^M (y_m + e^{-i\omega}) \overline{(y_m + e^{-i\omega})}}
    )
    -
    \log(
        \frac
            {\prod_{n=1}^N (p_n + i\omega) \overline{(p_n + i\omega)}}
            {\prod_{m=1}^M (q_m + i\omega) \overline{(q_m + i\omega)}}
    )
)^2 d\omega
$$

I know I could approximate the problem by discretization, but I don't want to do that.